# Are quotient varieties local complete intersections?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $G$ be a reductive group acting on the smooth affine variety $X$ such that the stabilizers are finite. Is it true that the quotient $X/G$ is a local complete intersection (LCI)? In particular, is the quotient of a smooth affine variety to the algebraic action of a finite group LCI? If no, is there any condition on the action that guarantees such a property?

Comment: Did you consider $\mathbb{C}^m$ modulo $\pm 1$? My recollection (might be wrong) is that this is not lci for $m = 3,4...$.

Comment: The quotient described by Geordie Williamson is the determinantal variety $S_1$ of symmetric $m\times m$ matrices of rank $\leq 1$, with the quotient  map given by $x\mapsto xx^{\rm T}$.

Comment: In other words, it is the (affine) cone over $\Bbb{P}^{m-1}$ embedded by the Veronese map. For $m\geq 3$ it is not Gorenstein, even less lci.

Comment: I think that $\mathbb{C}^m$ mod $\pm 1$ is Gorenstein when $m$ is even; more generally, the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^m$ by a subgroup of $SL(m,\mathbb{C})$ is Gorenstein, see Thm. 1 here: https://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/repo/ouka/all/12434/ojm11_01_01.pdf . But I agree that for all $m\geq 3$ it is not a complete intersection; see Theorem A here https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1982-06-02/S0273-0979-1982-14989-8/S0273-0979-1982-14989-8.pdf .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, $X/G$ need not in general even be Gorenstein, let alone a local complete intersection.

Actually, if the ground field has positive characteristic, $X/G$ may not even be Cohen-Macaulay (let alone Gorenstein, let alone LCI). For example, if $X = \mathbb{A}_k^4$, where $k = \overline{\mathbb{F}}_2$, and $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}/4$, with the action given by cyclically permuting the coordinate axes, then $X/G$ is not Cohen-Macaulay.

If the stabilizers all have order prime to the characteristic, then $X/G$ is Cohen-Macaulay, though, by the Hochster-Eagon theorem (Proposition 13 [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373744?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)). Without this condition, even Cohen-Macaulayness is a very delicate question, so from this point on I will assume this condition (orders of all stabilizers are coprime to the ground field characteristic) is met. For example, perhaps you are working over a characteristic zero field.

In this situation, an overly strong sufficient condition is that the stabilizers are generated by elements acting as pseudoreflections (i.e. elements $g$ in a stabilizer $G_x$, $x\in X$ whose fixed-point sets have codimension $1$ in the neighborhood of $x$). By the [Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Shephard%E2%80%93Todd_theorem), this forces $X/G$ to be *smooth*.

I am not aware of a more precise sufficient condition. However, it seems to me a *necessary* condition is that the stabilizers be generated by *bireflections*, i.e. elements $g$ in a stabilizer $G_x$, $x\in X$ whose fixed point sets have codimension $2$ in a neighborhood of $x$. See [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183548690) paper by Kac and Watanabe, which proves this in the situation of a linear action by a finite group on affine space, but it seems to me the argument works in general.

(Stabilizers-generated-by-bireflections is *not* sufficient. For examples of finite linear groups generated by bireflections whose action on affine 3-space over $\mathbb{C}$ has a quotient that is not a complete intersection, see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01165796).)